# robotic arm safety with proximity sensor

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello
I am working on a robotic arm.
The issue I'm working on right now is security.
My aim is to slow down the speed of the robotic arm if a human enters the environment while the robotic arm is moving.
The closer the human gets to the robotic arm, the more I want to slow down the robotic arm.

I used **setMaxVelocityScalingFactor** and **setMaxAccelerationScalingFactor** for this, but these can be used **before execution**.
The speed of the robotic arm should slow down **during execution**.
that is, I want to reduce the speed of the robotic arm when a human enters the environment **while the robotic arm is moving**.

Thank you so much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/416906/robotic-arm-safety-with-proximity-sensor/) by [omeranar1](https://answers.ros.org/users/45833/omeranar1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2023-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not aware of any standard ros package that has the behavior you ask for. I think you need to write custom code to implement this. If you are using `ros_control`, I'd investigate adding this new behavior to the `FollowJointTrajectory` Action Server.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2023-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2023-06-27**:
The `scaled_joint_trajectory_controller` in [UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_scaled_controllers](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_scaled_controllers) implements a version of the `JointTrajectoryController` which can dynamically update the 'rate' at which it executes trajectories. That *could* be something the OP could use.

Provided the "robotic arm" mentioned is `ros_control` compatible.

But: it's certainly not safety rated, so depending on the requirements would not be sufficient for a truly safe environment. Especially with humans close by.